# Running recursive Merge in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, a Card with a list of CardLines associated to it

```
Card (Unique: Code, Key)
----
Id | Code | Key

CardLine (FK: CardId, Unique: CardId, SubKey)
----
ID | CardId | Value | SubKey
```

Consider some data

```
Card
----
ID | CODE | Key
1  | C1   | K1
2  | C2   | K1
3  | C3   | K2

CardLine
----
ID | CardId | Value | SubKey
1  | C1     | 10    | SK1
2  | C1     | 20    | SK2
3  | C2     | 30    | SK1
4  | C2     | 40    | SK3
5  | C3     | 50    | SK4
```

Here, in Card table, C2 now needs to be converted to C1 (as C2 was an incorrect entry, it should have been C1). To do this, am trying to write a MERGE query, where in, if match, I need to run a sub-query to merge the CardLines for every match. Something like (pseudo-code)

```
MERGE into Card as target
USING (SELECT ID, Code, Key from Card where Code = 'C2')
ON (target.Code = 'C1' and target.Key = K1)
WHEN MATCH
THEN
-- Merge the Cardlines in a similar mananner for a matched card (subquery?) - basically
-- Delete Card if no more lines assigned to it after merge
WHEN NOT MATCH
-- just update the Code from C2 -> C1
```

Desired Output is

```
Card
----
ID | CODE | Key
1  | C1   | K1
3  | C3   | K2

CardLine
----
ID | CardId | Value | SubKey
1  | C1     | 40    | SK1   <-- merge of CardLine Id=1 and ID = 3, then 3 deleted
2  | C1     | 20    | SK2
4  | C1     | 40    | SK3   <-- no merge required, only product code update to C1 from C2
5  | C3     | 50    | SK4
```

Am not a SQL expert (.Net), so if this is not the right approach, would appreciate any right direction

Comment: You better show us the desired output.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: desired output added

Comment: Better, but now explain why in CardLine C1 SK1 became 30 etc

Comment: seems to me like using an [update cascade](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) would solve this problem better, but perhaps I'm missing something.